# How can I pass the artifact name from Jenkins to Rundeck

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

I have a `Rundeck` job configured with a `URL` option that allows you to select which `Jenkins` artifact to download based on the build number.

```
https://jenkins.server.com/plugin/rundeck/options/build?project=myproject&artifactRegex=.*rpm&limit=5&includeLastSuccessfulBuild=true&includeLastStableBuild=true
```

I'd like to initiate the `Rundeck` job from the `Jenkins` job that builds the archive. I thought it'd be as simple as passing the `BUILD_NUMBER` like `option=BUILD_NUMBER` but it doesn't resolve it.

Rundeck is doing a wget of the URL of the `Jenkins` artifact. Passing the `BUILD_NUMBER` just returns, can't find http://5 (as an example)

Any ideas on how I get `Rundeck` to accept a value from Jenkins and interpret it as the URL to the archive?

Comment: what is the url that rundeck is expected to download from?

Comment: https://jenkins.server.net/job/JenkinsJob/BuildNumber/artifact/releases/some.rpm - this is where Jenkins puts the artifact after it has done the Ant build

Comment: Can you try using the env variables JOB_URL, BUILD_NUMBER in conjunction to construct the url?

Comment: Yes, I can see that working. What frustrates me is Jenkins obviously know about the artifact and the URL; it puts the information on the page after the build completes. But there's no single variable to define it?